# Why do I need to set boost::archive::no_codecvt when using textarchive?

Tags: boost, archive

We have a class that serialises to boost::archive; but it inserts a 7 character string before the beginning of the archive.

Since upgrading to boost 1.61 from 1.56, this has started failing.

We've found that replacing the line:

```
boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive ia(ifs);
```

with

```
boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive ia(ifs, boost::archive::no_codecvt);
```

fixes the problem. But it would be nice to know why this has started failing between 1.56 and 1.61, and if this is the correct way to solve the issue.

```
// boost_archiving.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/exception/exception.hpp>
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

struct SimpleStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string string;
    double dub;

    template<typename T_ARCHIVE>

    void serialize(T_ARCHIVE &a, unsigned int version)
    {
        a & x;
        a & y;
        a & string;
        a & dub;
    }
};

typedef boost::array<char, 7> FileId;
const FileId FILE_ID = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };

void writeFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str());
    ofs.write(FILE_ID.data(), FILE_ID.size());
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);

    SimpleStruct simple;
    simple.x = 10;
    simple.y = 7;
    simple.string = "test";
    simple.dub = 2.5;

    oa << simple;
}


void readFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());

    FileId fileId;
    ifs.read(fileId.data(), fileId.size());
    if (ifs.good() && (fileId == FILE_ID))
    {
        boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive ia(ifs); // FAILS on 1.61 Swap this with the line below, or downgrade to boost 1.56
        // boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive ia(ifs, boost::archive::no_codecvt); 

        SimpleStruct simple;
        ia >> simple;

        std::cout
            << simple.x << " "
            << simple.y << " "
            << simple.string << " "
            << simple.dub << std::endl;
    }
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::string filename("archive.arch");
        writeFile(filename);
        readFile(filename);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sample Archive:

```
abcdefg22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 10 7 4 test 2.50000000000000000e+000
```

Comment: You should probably include hex-dumps of small sample archives

Comment: According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/implementation.html

`This character encoding is implemented by changing the locale of the i/o stream used by an archive when the archive is constructed, the stream locale is changed back to its original value. This action can be overridden by specifying boost::archive::no_codecvt when the archive is opened. In this case, the stream locale will not be changed by the serialization library.` 

So I think the characters at the beginning are the name of the locale.

Comment: @sehe Code already writes out a sample archive, but okay, added an example (it's a text archive) at the bottom.